# Is there a way get documents and the associated facets in one query with MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to run some query, get first X documents and the facet data on the full data set.
Is it possible in one query or I must do two queries for that? (one for documents and one for facet data)

For example, unifying the following two, to one query:

```
db.mycollection.find({tenant:"tenant1", class: "myclass"}).limit(20)
db.mycollection.aggregate( [ {$match: {tenant:"tenant1", class: "myclass"}}, 
                             {$facet: { "typeFacet": [{$sortByCount: "$type"}]}])
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: can you provide samples and expected result.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following aggregation will get the first 20 (as specified by the `$limit`) documents as the"xDocs" facet result, for the the documents that match filter in the `$match` stage. The "typeFacet" facet will apply the `$sortByCount`.

The `$facet` pipeline stage allows run multiple *facet* queries in parallel on the same set of documents (in this case all the documents in the collection).

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
{ $facet: { 
       xDocs: [
           { $match: { tenant: "tenant1", class: "myclass" } },
           { $limit: 20 }
       ],
       typeFacet: [
           { $sortByCount: "$type" }
       ]
} }
] )
```